# How to fill an array efficiently in Powershell

Tags: arrays, performance, powershell, append, array-initialization

I want to fill up a dynamic array with the same integer value as fast as possible using Powershell.
The Measure-Command shows that it takes 7 seconds on my system to fill it up.
My current code (snipped) looks like:

```
$myArray = @()
$length = 16385
for ($i=1;$i -le $length; $i++) {$myArray += 2}
```

<sup>(Full code can be seen on [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/81160f837827ad44e35f) or on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/307496/how-can-i-set-excel-to-always-import-all-columns-of-csv-files-as-text/527894#527894))</sup>

Consider that `$length` can change. But for better understanding I chose a fixed length.

**Q:** How do I speed up this Powershell code?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can repeat arrays, just as you can do with strings:

```
$myArray = ,2 * $length
```

This means »Take the array with the single element `2` and repeat it `$length` times, yielding a new array.«.

Note that you cannot really use this to create multidimensional arrays because the following:

```
$some2darray = ,(,2 * 1000) * 1000
```

will just create 1000 references to the inner array, making them useless for manipulation. In that case you can use a hybrid strategy. I have used

```
$some2darray = 1..1000 | ForEach-Object { ,(,2 * 1000) }
```

in the past, but below performance measurements suggest that

```
$some2darray = foreach ($i in 1..1000) { ,(,2 * 1000) }
```

would be a much faster way.

---

Some performance measurements:

```
Command                                                  Average Time (ms)
-------                                                  -----------------
$a = ,2 * $length                                                 0,135902 # my own
[int[]]$a = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Repeat(2, $length)           7,15362 # JPBlanc
$a = foreach ($i in 1..$length) { 2 }                             14,54417
[int[]]$a = -split "2 " * $length                                24,867394
$a = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $length; $i++) { 2 }                    45,771122 # Ansgar
$a = 1..$length | %{ 2 }                                         431,70304 # JPBlanc
$a = @(); for ($i = 0; $i -lt $length; $i++) { $a += 2 }       10425,79214 # original code
```

Taken by running each variant 50 times through `Measure-Command`, each with the same value for `$length`, and averaging the results.

Position 3 and 4 are a bit of a surprise, actually. Apparently it's much better to `foreach` over a range instead of using a normal `for` loop.

---

Code to generate above chart:

```
$length = 16384

$tests = '$a = ,2 * $length',
         '[int[]]$a = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Repeat(2, $length)',
         '$a = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $length; $i++) { 2 }',
         '$a = foreach ($i in 1..$length) { 2 }',
         '$a = 1..$length | %{ 2 }',
         '$a = @(); for ($i = 0; $i -lt $length; $i++) { $a += 2 }',
         '[int[]]$a = -split "2 " * $length'

$tests | ForEach-Object {
    $cmd = $_
    $timings = 1..50 | ForEach-Object {
        Remove-Variable i,a -ErrorAction Ignore
        [GC]::Collect()
        Measure-Command { Invoke-Expression $cmd }
    }
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Command = $cmd
        'Average Time (ms)' = ($timings | Measure-Object -Average TotalMilliseconds).Average
    }
} | Sort-Object Ave* | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap
```

Comment: +1 Concise, clear, constructive, comprehensive, and reproducible! (well, 4 out of 5 c's...)

Answer (score 6):

Avoid appending to an array in a loop. It's copying the existing array to a new array with each iteration. Do this instead:

```
$MyArray = for ($i=1; $i -le $length; $i++) { 2 }
```

Comment: +1 `$MyArray = for ($i=1; $i -le 16385; $i++) { 2 }`  runs in 0,05 seconds. much faster than my 7s :)

Answer (score 5):

Using PowerShell 3.0 you can use (need .NET Framework 3.5 or upper):

```
[int[]]$MyArray = ([System.Linq.Enumerable]::Repeat(2, 65000))
```

Using PowerShell 2.0

```
$AnArray = 1..65000 | % {2}
```

Comment: +1 `[int[]]$myArray = ([System.Linq.Enumerable]::Repeat(2, 16385))` runs in 0,03s

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you are trying. I tried looking at your code. But, `$myArray +=2` means you are just adding 2 as the element. For example, here is the output from my test code:

```
$myArray = @()
$length = 4
for ($i=1;$i -le $length; $i++) {
    Write-Host $myArray
    $myArray += 2
}

2
2 2
2 2 2
```

Why do you need to add 2 as the array element so many times?

If all you want is just fill the same value, try this:

```
$myArray = 1..$length | % { 2 }
```

Comment: He is just filling the array with some value ? the value is '2'

Comment: Question says he wants to fill the array with the same integer value. His problem is that appending to the array with `+=` is terribly slow.

Comment: Hmm! I understood that. But why? Why even find a better way to do something that is not needed. Anyway, he can use range operator as well.

Comment: I already appended the full code as github link just to avoid discussions about *Why*. If you look at the link, you will see that my powershell executes an Excel command for querying a CSV. And the parameter `TextFileColumnDataTypes` for that query needs an Array to know what data types the columns should be. A `2` stands for a string column, `1` for general, `9` to skip the entire column and so on. So: Long story short: I need a big array with the integer value 2.

Comment: +1 `$myArray = 1..16385 | % { 2 }` runs in 0,02 seconds. much faster than my 7s :)

Comment: When I tested `1..$length` it was reproducibly slower than `for ($i=1; $i -lt $length; $i++)`. Most likely because it's building a list before passing it into the `ForEach-Object` loop.

Answer (score -1):

If you need it really fast, then go with ArrayLists and Tuples:

```
$myArray = New-Object 'Collections.ArrayList'
$myArray = foreach($i in 1..$length) {
    [tuple]::create(2)
}
```

and if you need to sort it later then use this (normally a bit slower):

```
$myArray = New-Object 'Collections.ArrayList'
foreach($i in 1..$length) {
    $myArray.add(
        [tuple]::create(2)
    )
}
```

both versions are in the 20ms range for me ;-)

Comment: Though this is faster than the code in the question, what is the purpose of using a 1-value `Tuple`? That means you have to access the `Item1` property to get the value back, plus you're creating an `Object` to wrap every `Int32`, which will be a lot of garbage on larger lists. This doesn't hurt so bad because using the obsolete, non-generic `ArrayList` class means it'd be boxing each `Int32` in an `Object`, anyways. Rewriting as `$myArray = New-Object 'Collections.Generic.List[Int32]'; foreach($i in 1..$length) { $myArray.add(2) }` I get a 40% speedup and with less characters/complexity, too.

Comment: Also, each [property of a `Tuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.tuple-1.item1) is read-only, so if you want to change a list value (which is bound to happen because...what good is a list of repeated values that always stay the same?) your only option is to create a new `Tuple` to replace it.

Comment: even if the tuple-part is not really needed for the above challenge, it is worth to remember this to fill large read-only arrays with multiple columns/items per object. very handy to sort very large arrays/lookup-tables by different columns. without tuples and the need to sort anything.